# Laravel PHP - DOMDocument and DOMXpath on XML received from Amazon MWS

Tags: php, xml, laravel, xpath, domdocument

I'm working on a tool for getting reports from [Amazon MWS API](https://developer.amazonservices.com/doc/products/products/v20111001/php.html), using the Laravel framework.

I'm getting a response in xml when calling the Amazon API. The classes provided with the library are using DOMDocument and DOMXpath to extract the data from the xml but the content gets lost in the process and I'm trying to understand why.

A strange thing that is happening is that by running the same exact php scripts on PHPStorm it works perfectly! That is why I think it can be related to the Laravel framework but I can't figure out what is the issue

Please help!

**Below some info:**

The php scripts calls this function:

```
$response = MarketplaceWebService_Model_GetReportRequestListResponse::fromXML($httpResponse['ResponseBody']);
```

with this value for $httpResponse:

```
array:2 [▼
  "ResponseBody" => """
    <?xml version="1.0"?>\n
    <GetReportRequestListResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonaws.com/doc/2009-01-01/">\n
      <GetReportRequestListResult>\n
        <HasNext>true</HasNext>\n
        <ReportRequestInfo>\n
          <ReportType>_GET_FLAT_FILE_OPEN_LISTINGS_DATA_</ReportType>\n
          <ReportProcessingStatus>_DONE_</ReportProcessingStatus>\n
          <EndDate>2017-11-15T04:06:35+00:00</EndDate>\n
          <Scheduled>true</Scheduled>\n
          <ReportRequestId>52722017485</ReportRequestId>\n
          <StartedProcessingDate>2017-11-15T04:07:11+00:00</StartedProcessingDate>\n
          <SubmittedDate>2017-11-15T04:07:04+00:00</SubmittedDate>\n
          <StartDate>2017-11-15T03:51:35+00:00</StartDate>\n
          <CompletedDate>2017-11-15T04:07:17+00:00</CompletedDate>\n
          <GeneratedReportId>7148302909017485</GeneratedReportId>\n
        </ReportRequestInfo>\n
        <ReportRequestInfo>\n
        <NextToken>qjb2pyR8Y//2jpZedg0wbVuY6vtoszFEpNskn2hXruMK87IwBCsqTss38OFevvFPICyhlLgHd4gqVtOYt5i3YQjj4iSEMGHo3mNw/mSHKWv7metcux95rRMwNETnEZDkMI0ILgGwe7qb+ZFNg ▶
      </GetReportRequestListResult>\n
      <ResponseMetadata>\n
        <RequestId>e5b2496f-8835-4a40-a535-d467ec38e5e6</RequestId>\n
      </ResponseMetadata>\n
    </GetReportRequestListResponse>\n
    """
  "ResponseHeaderMetadata" => MarketplaceWebService_Model_ResponseHeaderMetadata {#177 ▶}
]
```

MarketplaceWebService_Model_GetReportRequestListResponse::fromXML looks like this:

```
    public static function fromXML($xml)
    {
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->loadXML($xml);
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);


        $xpath->registerNamespace('a', 'http://mws.amazonaws.com/doc/2009-01-01/');
        $response = $xpath->query('//a:GetReportRequestListResponse');

        if ($response->length == 1) {
            return new MarketplaceWebService_Model_GetReportRequestListResponse(($response->item(0))); 
        } else {
            throw new Exception ("Unable to construct MarketplaceWebService_Model_GetReportRequestListResponse from provided XML. 
                                  Make sure that GetReportRequestListResponse is a root element");
        }

    }
```

By printing the variables on the browser I can see that **$dom** looks like this:

```
DOMDocument {#178 ▼
  +nodeName: "#document"
  +nodeValue: null
  +nodeType: XML_DOCUMENT_NODE
  +parentNode: null
  +childNodes: DOMNodeList {#190 ▶}
  +firstChild: DOMElement {#192 …}
  +lastChild: DOMElement {#192 …}
  +previousSibling: null
  +nextSibling: null
  +attributes: null
  +ownerDocument: null
  +namespaceURI: null
  +prefix: ""
  +localName: null
  +baseURI: "/Users/DreamCatcher-2/Google Drive/Business worth trying/Exclusives Ninja/Laravel_PHP_Projects/amazon-tool-2/public/"
  +textContent: ""
  +doctype: null
  +implementation: DOMImplementation {#199 ▶}
  +documentElement: DOMElement {#192 …}
  +actualEncoding: null
  +encoding: null
  +xmlEncoding: null
  +standalone: true
  +xmlStandalone: true
  +version: "1.0"
  +xmlVersion: "1.0"
  +strictErrorChecking: true
  +documentURI: "/Users/DreamCatcher-2/Google Drive/Business worth trying/Exclusives Ninja/Laravel_PHP_Projects/amazon-tool-2/public/"
  +config: null
  +formatOutput: false
  +validateOnParse: false
  +resolveExternals: false
  +preserveWhiteSpace: true
  +recover: false
  +substituteEntities: false
  xml: """
    <?xml version="1.0"?>\n
    <GetReportRequestListResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonaws.com/doc/2009-01-01/">\n
      <GetReportRequestListResult>\n
        <HasNext>true</HasNext>\n
        <ReportRequestInfo>\n
          <ReportType>_GET_FLAT_FILE_OPEN_LISTINGS_DATA_</ReportType>\n
          <ReportProcessingStatus>_DONE_</ReportProcessingStatus>\n
          <EndDate>2017-11-15T04:06:35+00:00</EndDate>\n
          <Scheduled>true</Scheduled>\n
          <ReportRequestId>52722017485</ReportRequestId>\n
          <StartedProcessingDate>2017-11-15T04:07:11+00:00</StartedProcessingDate>\n
          <SubmittedDate>2017-11-15T04:07:04+00:00</SubmittedDate>\n
          <StartDate>2017-11-15T03:51:35+00:00</StartDate>\n
          <CompletedDate>2017-11-15T04:07:17+00:00</CompletedDate>\n
          <GeneratedReportId>7148302909017485</GeneratedReportId>\n
        </ReportRequestInfo>\n
        <ReportRequestInfo>\n
        <NextToken>ZeFtJfeKgpv2jpZedg0wbVuY6vtoszFEpNskn2hXruMK87IwBCsqTss38OFevvFPICyhlLgHd4gqVtOYt5i3YQjj4iSEMGHo3mNw/mSHKWv7metcux95rRMwNETnEZDkMI0ILgGwe7qb+ZFNg ▶
      </GetReportRequestListResult>\n
      <ResponseMetadata>\n
        <RequestId>4030b010-e42a-4ba2-af5e-b2d6e44649fe</RequestId>\n
      </ResponseMetadata>\n
    </GetReportRequestListResponse>\n
    """
}
```

and the argument passed to the constructor (**$response->item(0)**) looks like this:

```
DOMElement {#180 ▼
  +nodeName: "GetReportRequestListResponse"
  +nodeValue: ""
  +nodeType: XML_ELEMENT_NODE
  +parentNode: DOMDocument {#178 …}
  +childNodes: DOMNodeList {#193 ▶}
  +firstChild: DOMText {#195 …}
  +lastChild: DOMText {#197 …}
  +previousSibling: null
  +nextSibling: null
  +attributes: DOMNamedNodeMap {#200 ▶}
  +ownerDocument: DOMDocument {#178 …}
  +namespaceURI: "http://mws.amazonaws.com/doc/2009-01-01/"
  +prefix: ""
  +localName: "GetReportRequestListResponse"
  +baseURI: "/Users/DreamCatcher-2/Google Drive/Business worth trying/Exclusives Ninja/Laravel_PHP_Projects/amazon-tool-2/public/"
  +textContent: ""
  +tagName: "GetReportRequestListResponse"
  +schemaTypeInfo: null
}
```

As you can see the **nodeValue** attribute is empty in the $response and in the $dom, but the $dom still has the information about the XML, while it's lost in the $response.

Any idea? Thanks in advance and please let me know if I can provide more information

Comment: If you look at the output of  $response->item(0), the value of nodeValue is blank, BUT there are child nodes, so the node contains data.

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction. It was not an issue related to DOMDocument or DOMXpath but rather related to the second part of the code. Amazon MWS library creates a new instance of a class based on the content of the generate xPath file and that content had the correct name of the class but not the correct filepath to load it. I didn't think about it because it wasn't throwing an error for that, just it was returning an empty response. Thanks @NigelRen !